# Terraform detects changes and adds/removes resources when executed apply/plan for next time to changes made in aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Terraform detects changes and adds/removes resources when executed apply/plan for next time to changes made in aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration expiration value. Earlier all the s3 bucket resource were under same block I haven't faced any issue in the deployment. After separation of s3 resource in separate blocks I am facing this issue

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "karthik_s3" {
  bucket = module.naming.name

  tags = module.tags.default_tags
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "karthik_s3_versioning" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.karthik_s3.id
  versioning_configuration {
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" "karthik_s3_encryption" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.karthik_s3.bucket

  rule {
    apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
      kms_master_key_id = aws_kms_key.kms_key.arn
      sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "karthik_s3_lifecycle" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.karthik_s3.id
  rule {
    id      = "expire_all_files"

    expiration {
      days = 30
    }

    noncurrent_version_expiration {
      noncurrent_days  = 30
    }

    status = "Enabled"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "karthik_s3_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.karthik_s3.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.karthik_s3_policy_document.json
}
```

I am trying to update the expiration value of the aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration from 30 to 90days. when changes are made in code and executed terraform apply it detects changes in s3 bucket resource where there are no changes are made.

Comment: What is the plan output?

Comment: Planned output is to see the updated expiration days in lifecycle policy of s3 bucket

Comment: **Show** the plan output.